# WPF MVVM Light enabling button if data grid row is selected

Tags: wpf, button, datagrid, wpf-controls, mvvm-light

I can't seem to find a straight answer on this anywhere.  I have a button that I want to Disable UNTIL a DataGrid row is selected.  Doesn't matter which row.  Once it's deselected I would like it to be disabled again.

Comment: Are you allowing multiselection?

Comment: No.  I am not.  Just single

Comment: button is inside the datagrid column or it is outside of data grid, perhaps a sample xaml will be beneficial to understand the same.

Comment: The data grids are in a tab control.  The buttons Add and Edit are below the data grid, but not a part of.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here you go

```
<StackPanel>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dGrid">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding}"
                                Header="A Column" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <sys:String>item 1</sys:String>
        <sys:String>item 2</sys:String>
        <sys:String>item 3</sys:String>
        <sys:String>item 4</sys:String>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button x:Name="button"
            Content="A Button">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItems.Count,ElementName=dGrid}"
                                 Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled"
                                Value="False" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

above example will place a trigger on `SelectedItems.Count` of DataGrid and will disable the button if it is zero

this is a pure xaml solution, other solution may also be possible with converters or vm properties

---

**EDIT**

as requested here is a sample to do it without using Name attribute

```
<StackPanel>
    <DataGrid>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding}"
                                Header="A Column" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <sys:String>item 1</sys:String>
        <sys:String>item 2</sys:String>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button Content="A Button">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Parent.Children[0].SelectedItems.Count,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                 Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled"
                                Value="False" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
        </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

above code assume the datagrid to be the first child of the parent container `Parent.Children[0]`, you may adjust it as per your needs.

Comment: Is it possible to do without having a Name attribute on the data grid?

Comment: would be bit difficult, if you can share your exact xaml to be used then perhaps we can find a way around. button may not require a name, you may remove it.

Answer (score 7):

It's much easier to just use the automatic evaluation of int to bool provided by WPF:

```
IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=YourDataGrid, Path=SelectedItems.Count}"
```

Answer (score 1):

In XAML:

```
IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=DataGridName, Path=SelectedItems.Count}"
```

In MainMethod:

```
// depends how much do you need
if(dataGrid.SelectedItems.Count >= 1)
            {
                Button.IsEnabled = true;
            }
```

And create

```
void dataGrid_OnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender != null)
            {
                DataGrid grid = sender as DataGrid;
                if (grid != null && grid.SelectedItems != null && grid.SelectedItems.Count == 1)
                {
                    DataGridRow dgr = grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(grid.SelectedItem) as DataGridRow;
                    if (!dgr.IsMouseOver)
                    {
                        (dgr as DataGridRow).IsSelected = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

And IsEnabled property will be able to change in the realtime.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using MVVM Light, you can use the CanExecute property of the RelayCommand.

My view is assuming a DataContext (my ViewModel) with an ICommand type property called ButtonCommand, an ObservableCollection property as the ItemsSource of the DataGrid, and a YourClass property as the SelectedItem of the DataGrid.

**View**

```
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Button"
            Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}"/>
    <DataGrid SelectionMode="Single"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRow}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Some Property"
                                Binding="{Binding SomeProperty}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

I then use a method that returns a bool as the CanExecute parameter of the ButtonCommand. When my SelectedRow becomes null the button will disable automatically. And likewise, when I select a row the button will enable automatically.

**ViewModel**

```
private ICommand _ButtonCommand;
public ICommand ButtonCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_ButtonCommand == null)
        {
            _ButtonCommand = new RelayCommand(() => MethodToCall(), () => MethodCanExecute());
        }

        return _ButtonCommand;
    }
}

private bool MethodCanExecute()
{
    return SelectedRow != null;
}

private void MethodToCall()
{
    MessageBox.Show(SelectedRow.SomeProperty);
}
```